# PHP CSV Manager class

Tags: php, class, csv

I search a lot on it,  but didn't find any special class for it. who's create csv file, update (append also), delete record from csv file..

Does any one know about any php class library for this work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [PEAR::File_CSV_DataSource](http://pear.php.net/package/File_CSV_DataSource).

Comment: I checked it, but i think it is so complex for taking this type of work...there is some extra files included which is not available in downloaded folder....